# FilterExpression Syntax error using boto3 dynamodb client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to query dynamodb using the low-level client api of boto3.

```
   response = client.query(
        TableName='People',
        IndexName='country-index',
        KeyConditionExpression='country = :country',
        FilterExpression="attribute_not_exists('age') AND attribute_not_exists('address')",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":country":{"S": "USA"}
        },
        Limit=100
    )
```

I get a syntax error :

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query
>   operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "'", near:
>   "('age"

The documentation in boto3 redirects to Amazon developer guide. I was not able to find the syntax for client.query(...). The examples listed there are for using table.query(...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please change the `FilterExpression` as mentioned below.

```
FilterExpression="attribute_not_exists(age) AND attribute_not_exists(address)",
```

Comment: Great! Is there a documentation which describes whether to "&" or "AND" etc. I also wanted to know the syntax for greater than, less than etc.

Comment: The docs linked^^ are for boto3, but this filter expression is using the expression syntax common to all SDKs for dynamodb, the one that you pass directly to the REST API, docs for that are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html